# Is it possible to preview arbitrary formats in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, file-format, thumbnails, previews

I recently found out that Nautilus (Ubuntu 12.04 at least) can show thumbnails of files of non-image formats, for example (data grapher) `grace` files (`.agr`) shows a small version of the graph contained in its data. Obviously, there some library or script that is processing the file, making the image, and allowing nautilus to show a small version of it.

This made me think that in principle any file that potentially can be processed into an image can serve as a Nautilus thumbnail.

For example, a `.tex` file (which can be converted to `.pdf`) or a gnuplot script can be displayed as a thumbnail when possible.

In the case of `.tex` file, the correspoding .pdf can be created by the command `pdflatex file.tex`.

The question is, how can I tell Nautilus to create a thumbnail for an arbitrary format and how do I specify the commands to do so within Nautilus?

---

**Update 2014,**

I still didn't manage to preview anything with the answer posted, I created this script in `/usr/bin/tex-thumbnailer`:

```
pdflatex $1
convert -density 300 ${1%.*}.pdf -resize 25% $2
```

and a file `/usr/share/thumbnailers/tex.thumbnailer`:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=tex-thumbnailer
Exec=tex-thumbnailer %u %o
MimeType=text/x-tex;
```

I can't make nautilus to generate/show the preview even for simple TeX files. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/thumbnailer.html.en)'s the documentation on how to add a new thumbnailer.

You need to add two keys on gconf:

- /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-foo/enable (boolean)
- /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-foo/command (string)

Where `application@x-foo` is the MimeType for the kind of file you want to generate the thumbnails. Set `enable` to True and `command` to the command to create the thumbnail.

To add one with gconftool-2:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-foo/enable --type bool true
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-foo/command --type string "application-x-foo-thumbnailer %i %o %s"
```

The folders are created automatically. `%i` is the input file, `%o` where to write the output file (png) and `%s` the size of the thumbnail.

And [here](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/mime.html.en)'s how to add a MimeType for custom files.

---

I found another way which seems easier, you can create a file in `/usr/share/thumbnailers/` for example foo.thumbnailer:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/application-x-foo-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/application-x-foo-thumbnailer %i %o %s
MimeType=application/x-foo;
```

You can separate several MimeTypes with `;`.

Comment: thanks, how do I exactly create the "folder" application@x-foo inside /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers?, when I right click I only get "New Key..." (other options, grayed out) (Ubuntu 12.04, gconf-editor 3.0.1, both as root or as user)

Comment: thank you, for the detailed answer. First, for the files I want the reported type is "text/x-tex", therefore I added the keys in: /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/text@x-tex/. Second the conversion requires two steps .tex->.pdf->.png, so I use this as the composite command "pdflatex %i && convert `basename %i .tex`.pdf %o". After restarting, still doesn't work. maybe it is the fact that this is a "text-*" file and not an "application-*" file. Or maybe the parser gets confused by the composite command. I'll mark this as the accepted answer but any help is still appreciated.

Comment: Probably the later, you could try creating a bash script with all the steps inside so it's just one command.